# $A$ and $B$ homeomorphic if they are different sets in bigger topological space

Tags: general-topology

In topological space $X$, suppose $A$ is an open set, while $B$ is not, is it possible that $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Hint: Let $X$ be a closed interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that the subspaces $A$ and $B$ are homemorphic, then this is possible. Take for example $X = \{1,2\}$ with the topology $\{\emptyset, \{1\}, X\}$. Then $A = \{1\}$ and $\{B\} = \{2\}$ together with the subspace topology respectively are homeomorphic, but $A$ is open in $X$ while $B$ is not.

If you mean that there exists a homeomorphism $\varphi \colon X \to X$  with $\varphi(A) = B$ then this is not possible, because $A$ being open is equivalent to $\varphi(A)$ being open. So while $A$ and $B$ may be homeomorphic, no such homeomorphism comes from the restriction of an homeomorphism $X \to X$ (by restriction).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the [Sierpinski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space) $X=\{0,1\}$. $\{1\}$ is open, $\{0\}$ is not, but both are one-element spaces, hence homeomorphic.

Another example can be seen by taking $X=[0,1]$. $A=X$ is open, $B=[\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}]$ is not, but $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic.